# Trying to search two columns using sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to search a two columns in a mysql table using sequelize, using the same term.  So for instance, I want to search in a table called users, columns of first name and lastname, using a var called user input.  I've only managed to make it's either first and last, rather than first OR last.  How would I preform this query?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out the docs: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/querying/#where

Basically what you need to do is to use an `$or` operator in a query:

```
$or: [{a: 5}, {a: 6}]  // (a = 5 OR a = 6)
```

Comment: I did, just didn't get the syntax correct. Thank you.